# Android View with Tabs without having an activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a background service running, displaying some views as system_overlay to provide aditional information for the currently active app.

To configure the hud display i want to show the user another overlay view to change some parameters.

The point of using system_overlay for the settings view too is to not be the active activity. Otherwise the original activity for which I provide the information gets closed by the system sometimes while the settings view is displayed because this other app uses a very big amount of ram
(Thats why I don't want to use an activity for the settings view)

---

**The Problem:** I want something like a TabHost with a ViewPager in my settings view but without having an activity.

And even if I get the ViewPager working I can't load the contents because they are currently only available as fragments.

---

**The Question:** From what i read, fragments don't work without an activity, so what would be the right way to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your xml file which you want to inflate for your view,add these both in that xml layout instead of using other things for a tab view.

```
  <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    app:pstsTextAllCaps="true"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#ff9900"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:pstsUnderlineColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">
</com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

in your gradle dependencies add this line:-
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'

try it,hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Sry for not accepting your answer. I was looking for a solution without more external libraries and completle forgot this thread.